# 404 error not work for /%post_id%/%postname%.html

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i use /%post_id%/%postname%.html in my wordpress permalink.
404 eror dont work for  this permalink if post or page not exist.

but for another link 404 work good.
this is my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-284-permalinks-issue-with-404-error-not-found) might be help you

set apache to "AllowOverride All"

mod_rewrite is present, .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wikiarr_prd/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wikiarr_prd/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Permalinks structure:

/%postname%_%post_id%.html
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but not work with this method.in other site in my vps work correct but in this site not work.